# Kernel panic - not syncing:Attempted to kill init

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm using the buildroot version-20011.02 for kernel, toolchain and filesystem.My customized board ARMV7 cortexA9 SoC.Kernel version is 3.18.41.
Build the kernel(uImage), Buildroot toolchain, rootfs.tar.gz.
Enable the filesystem tyep ext4 in buildroot and also in kernel.
Extracting this rootfs.tar.gz to /export/users/buildroot/.
exporting this directory by using
`exportfs -a, exportfs -rv` and restart the nfs server.It seems everything is fine on nfs server side.
Here I'm sharing the "make menuconfig"  system configuration -->

```
Init system (BusyBox)  --->
```

Even I tried with   `Init system (systemV)  --->`
with bootargs as `bootargs console=ttyAM0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rw rootwait ip=dhcp nfsroot=192.168.1.40:/export/users/buildroot,tcp,v3 init=/sbin/init`
Every time I'm getting below log:

```
VFS: mounted fs via nfs  
devtmpfs is mounted.  
Kernel panic - not syncing:Attempted to kill init, exit code=0x000000b
```

Please help me out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try to isolate your problem. What if you build another kernel version?
I suppose that you've read https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt that.

Comment: Is that the entire stack in the log? If there is more it could be useful.

Comment: What is /sbin/init? Is it softlink to systemd or just script?

Comment: @AlexBender, I didn't try with another kernel version since made the changes in board file and other source files to customize this into our SoC.I want to stick with this kernel to resolve this issue.if you are suggesting i will give a try with another kernel.Do you think is it a problem with kernel?   Yes I've read link you shared, its seems kernel command line i.e bootargs is proper thats why its mounting to nfs server from the log. Still if you are feeling I'm missing something in bootargs please feel free to comment.

Comment: @kabanus, I agree it would be more useful if i will share complete log, but sorry I'm working in so much secure environment. What I remember here I'm sharing.      VFS: mounted fs via nfs  
devtmpfs is mounted.  Freeing unused kenel memory...
Kernel panic - not syncing:Attempted to kill init, exit code=0x000000b, Its seem kernel is trying to find that init , but not able find. I'm assuming.We need to debug this way what could be problem kernel can find this init after mounting nfs filesystem.

Comment: @user2699113, its a binary of rootfs, it is softlink to /bin/busybox

Comment: @shaikhkamal and what about trying not to use NFS. Is it possible for you?

Comment: there is similar problem: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/my-linux-kernel-boot-meet-the-error-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exit-code%3D0x0000000b-4175610787/

Comment: @AlexBender, Initially I tried with initramfs with enabling all configuration in kernel and buildroot to support initramfs , but it was crashing. Tried with nfs at least I'm getting better  results, then I stick with this nfs.

Comment: @AlexBender, Thanks for sharing this link, yes it's similar problem,but only one difference I'm not getting any segmentation fault just after "Freeing unused kernel memory---"In this link issue was resolved by libc.so.-- corruption, even earlier checked this init depency library by using compiler prefix -ldd command, it was showing original libc.so softlink was not found, then copied this libc.so from buildroot to nfs directory, then creating same softlink , then just skip kernel verification that time.tomorrow I will try kernel and update you

Comment: As I'm and not kernel developer, nor the one who knows it at decent level -- you'd better ask in IRC channels related to kernel and ARM boards. It's my suggestion. Despite I'd like to help, bud don't have required level of knowledge.

Comment: Make sure that /bin/busybox is statically linked. Try to link another static binary file instead of /bin/busybox (systemd?)

Comment: @AlexBender, I checked   arm-linux-ldd init - checking the sub-depends for not found. libc.so.0 => not found.(0x0000000), then i checked rootfs lib directory this library already there and linking properly. its seems something went wrong in init binary.

Comment: @user2699113, I don't want to build  statically.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

As you said, there is a log like below.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing:Attempted to kill init, exit code=0x000000b
```

This means `init`(busybox) is exited and the exit code is `0xb`.
So kernel goes into panic.
Maybe this is caused by a network problem. But we cannot conclude this is due to network or not, for now.

You said, you saw crashing, without NFS.
I think resolving that crash maybe better way to solve this situation.

Please share crash log without NFS configuration. If you share log, I will check it.

Comment: Now I tried with initramfs still having same issue what i'm getting in nfs.

Comment: One thing I observed when I disable the I-cache in kernel its working fine, but I checked with other boards like beaglebone they are enabling this I-cahe. I need with I-cache enabled, its seem some kernel configuration needs to be proper. Please anybody has idea how to solve this issue with enabling the I-cache in kernel. If anybody has  working ARMv7 cortex a9 kernel  configuration for buildroot, please share, meantime I'm checking my kernel configuration.